"Listen to this page" menu item in Chrome - Where is it?
The following official Google Chrome support page describes a feature called: "Listen to this page".
However, when I follow all the instructions on that page, I still can't find that elusive Listen to this page menu item.
I noticed the note that says that this feature "isn't available yet on all websites", but I tried on the most likely sites to be supported by it (nytimes.com, wikipedia.org, etc.) - to no avail.
If this feature wasn't silently removed by Google, can you provide an example of a website that does demonstrate this feature?

I am using the latest & greatest version of Chrome for Android: 131.0.6778.200, on a Pixel 4a running Android 13:

Yet, I am still unable to see the Listen to this page menu item, even after reloading the page several times:

I am also unable to view it on the Toolbar shortcut settings:


Viewing a specific question on the Android Enthusiasts site as tested in Chrome for Android (Version 131.0.6778.200) running on Pixel 6a with Android 13 does bring up Listen to this page in the 3 dot menu after a period of time after loading the page. A few times I had to reload the 3 dot menu for the Listen to this page option to show up.
I was not able to get the Listen to this page to load up on the home screen of the Android Enthusiasts site. Probably as there is some algorithm checking if the page has a blob of text rather than bunch of headers/bullet points/formatting.
If you do like this feature you can add it to your toolbar in Chrome for Android by going: 3 dot menu -> Settings -> (scroll down to) Toolbar shortcut -> (select) Listen to this page.
Note again that the homepage of Android Enthusiasts doesn't have the "Listen to this page" icon while selecting an question to read will have the icon show up in the toolbar after a few seconds.
Sadly the "Listen to this page" will only read out the question part of the post and the only way I've found to vocalize the answer is to select the answer text and then hitting the 3 dot menu on the selection and pick "Read aloud".

Thank you for this detailed and very helpful answer. Unfortunately, even after following your example, I am unable to view that menu item. I am using the same Chrome version as yours. I updated my post with screenshots that may shed a clue to the mystery.

@sfinja I just tested on Galaxy M12, Android 13, Chrome 131, and I could see the "Listen to this page" menu on Stack Exchange pages. Have you checked the languages setting on the Chrome?

@AndrewT. Yes, my Chrome's Languages settings reads: Current device language: English (United States) but I'm still unable to view the Listen to this page menu item.

@sfinja Can you try while connected to a WiFi access point. Oddly I could still select text to "Read aloud" while offline but didn't see 'Listen to this page'

@MorrisonChang  I tried with a WiFi access point, too, but I'm still unable to view the Listen to this page menu item. This is very weird, both you and AndrewT can view it while I can't - on 2 different phones running Android 13. Could an undocumented setting be influencing this?

@sfinja As a test I downloaded the Chrome Beta app and didn't log into my Google account, I still logged into Stackexchange.com . Curiously the Listen to this page failed to show up but when I did log back in the feature was reenabled. Attempted to use feature flag chrome://flags/#read-aloud shows it to be enabled in the setting panel but unless I am logged into my Google account, Listen to this page features doesn't show up.

@sfinja I would review your Google Account privacy settings: https://myaccount.google.com/data-and-privacy to see if anything there may be the trigger. As a reference I do allow Google for "Web & App Activity" Be aware I don't know how fast any account level changes will work / affect the phone.

Looks like Chromium has a source code to determine the menu visibility if someone is interested. I haven't explored much, other than finding that there's this code.

@MorrisonChang  Chrome Beta app it is. On same exact smartphone, I have both Chrome 131.0.6778.200 and  Chrome Beta app installed. Only  Chrome Beta app displays Listen to this page menu item (and works as you described). Andrew's comment providing the source code was also priceless, as it gave me an insight to possible settings, but none of the settings I tried solved the issue. I am marking your answer as accepted because, thanks to your answer, I can finally experience that feature. Thank you.

I am adding my own version to the answer (while keeping @MorrisonChang's the accepted one) because:

The solution is "well" hidden in the last comment to the accepted answer.
Finding the solution was a long and winding process that merits documenting it.

TL;DR
Only the Chrome Beta app displays the Listen to this page menu item (and works as described in the accepted answer)

Background
In addition to my original post, it turns out that I wasn't the first one to encounter this challenge:

"Listen to this page" disappeared?
Listen to this page button went missing. Is there a way to get it back?
"listen to this page" is not showing up any way to fix this issue?
The "Listen to this page" is missing from my Pixel 6's Chrome

The Troubleshooting Process

Thanks to the first reply to my question (the accepted answer), I first tried to view this menu item on this web page you're reading right now.

I then tried it on a different device (Samsung running Android 13).

I then tried to toy with Chrome's language setting (UK English instead of US English).

I tried with a WiFi access point instead of 4G/LTE connection.

I tried switching from Default to Enabled 5 different settings related to chrome://flags/#read-aloud.

I then used @AndrewT's answer to try and figure out which other settings could be involved, via a breakdown of what the method prepareReadAloudMenuItem(...) does:

Language Support: The feature must be available for the current page's language.

Page Content: The page must contain readable text content.

Feature Flag: The "Read Aloud" feature flag must be enabled in Chrome's experimental features.

User Settings: The user must have enabled the "Read Aloud" feature in their Chrome settings.

Device Capability: The device must support text-to-speech functionality.

Page Type: The current page must not be a special Chrome page (like Settings or New Tab).

Browser State: Chrome must not be in incognito mode.


Only if all these conditions are met, the "Listen to this page" menu item will appear in the overflow menu...
Despite all of that, I have not been able to display the "Listen to this page" menu item on the latest & greatest Chrome for Android: 131.0.6778.200. At this moment, only Chrome Beta 132.0.6834.56 supports this function.
